# Lightning split View not available for custom visualforce page

Tags: lightning-console

I can see the split view enabled for the object's list views in salesforce lightning by default. My requirement is, i have a custom VF Page which needs to be always pinned on the left. This can be achieved in classic console app by choosing the list placements(as shown in image below). In lightning, since the lists(object's list) are pinned by default, I couldn't find a way to pin my custom VF page. Is there any other options to achieve this in lightning.

[image: classic console - Pin page to left]

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution? Thanks.